# I am not including any file in my theme then how wordpress functions are working

Tags: php, wordpress

Something that I just can't understand is how the Wordpress functions are loaded in. When I am adding an action to a Wordpress hook like this.

```
 <?php

function test() {
echo "Test";
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','test');

?>
```

This code works for what I want to do but where is this add_action function coming from. I know Wordpress is taking care of it somehow but I just don't understand how I am able to call it without actually including a file. I tried to include the file in another file that would be included before this file but then I would get a function that is not defined error. I just really want to know the logic behind this.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this function initialized in wp-includes/plugin.php :

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
    return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

You can use the function wherever this file is included.

Wordpress has this documentation and more @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: But I am not including plugin.php in my file and I am still able to call that function that is what I don't understand

Comment: Please elaborate. What file is the code you've provided included in? And what directory is it in? Is this all the code of the file?

Comment: The code I have given is all the code I used. I placed this in the functions.php file when I was trying to create a custom Wordpress theme. I believe the functions.php file is automatically executed by Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

It's work like, the first file that runs on open WordPress site is index.php which required wp-blog-header.php

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
 require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

then wp-blog-header.php require wp-load.php and template-loader.php

```
// Load the WordPress library.
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
// Set up the WordPress query.
wp();
// Load the theme template.
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

here wp-load.php file require wp-config.php

```
if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') ) {
   /** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );
}
```

and wp-config.php file require wp-settings.php

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

and wp-settings loads wp-includes/plugin.php file

```
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
// Include files required for initialization.
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/default-constants.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php' );
```

and wp-includes/plugin.php file have add_action function in it

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
   return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

and wp-includes/template-loader.php load the theme template.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

Comment: I know how it works what my question is is why am I able to use this function without including the file.

Comment: Hope this will help you in getting the idea of how all the function work in WordPress theme